# Spectrum Y(f) of the signal $\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}y(t) = \rect(t/T_0) \cos(2\pi f_0t)$

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

I have to compute the spectrum $Y(f)$ of the signal $y(t) = \rect(\frac{t}{T_0}) \cos(2\pi f_0t)$ with $f_0 = \frac{1}{T_0}$.

What I have done so far is the following:

I know from my notes that $\rect(\frac{t}{T_0})$ in spectrum form is $T_0\sinc(2\pi fT_0)$

and $\cos(2\pi f_0t)$ is in spectrum form equal to $\frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+ \delta(f+f_0)]$.

From Fourier Transform Theorems we have convolution operation of $x(t)y(t)$ which equal to $X(t)*Y(t)$ and in this case $*$ star indicate the convolution operation.

Now if we use convolution on this we would have

#### Updated

$T_0\sinc(2\pi fT_0) * \frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+ \delta(f+f_0)]$

Using this hint from one other post in dsp stack (What is the convolution of 2 dirac functions?) $f(t)∗δ(t−a)=f(t−a)$. I would have something like the following:

$T_0 \sinc(2\pi fT_0 - f_0) + T_0 \sinc(2\pi fT_0 +f_0)$

Is this correct? Did I miss something along the way? For plotting this on matlab I would have to plot the result of this last line (convolution of $X(t)*Y(t)$) ?

Comment: A) Double check the spectrum of the cosine. b) you can do the convolution by easily by hand since you have $\delta()$ functions which have very nice convolution properties

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks! Do you mean with A) i should change $f_0$ in to $\frac{1}{T_0}$ in the cosine. Or something else in the spectrum of cosine?

Comment: As Hilmar suggested the spectrum of the cosine is not correct as written; it's close but worth your effort to review that carefully rather than just give you the answer here. Update your question with the correct result and we'll confirm. (Or explain why you think each term would have $e^{j()}$ terms)